Partial override of object type parameter with default values
In ADO, I want to partially override object type parameter using templates.
For example:
main.yml
parameters:
   - name: person 
     type: object 
     default:
        first_name: "Jane"
        last_name: "Doe"
        role: "Student"

- template: templates/template.yml 
  parameters:
      person: ${{parameters.person}}

template.yml
parameters:
   - name: person
     type: object

Here, I want to send object parameter, person, only with role: "Teacher" like this, and in template.yml, person object's first_name is "Jane" and last_name is "Doe", but role will be "Teacher". Is this possible?
project.yml
extends: 
   template: template/main/main.yml
   parameters: 
      person:
         role: "Teacher"

I tried the code above, but in template-yml, it could not parse first_name or last_name.

You cannot partially override an object parameter in the pipelines via passing part of the elements directly.
As a workaround, you can replace the role with your target value when pass the parameter to your template.
The main.yml:
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

parameters:
- name: person
  type: object
  default:
    first_name: "Jane"
    last_name: "Doe"
    role: "Student"

steps:
- script: |
    echo "${PERSON}"
  env:
    PERSON: ${{ convertToJson(parameters.person) }}

- template: templates/template.yml
  parameters:
    person_update:
      ${{each pair in parameters.person}}:
        ${{if and( eq(pair.key, 'role'), eq(pair.value, 'student' )) }}:
          ${{pair.key}}: 'Teacher'
        ${{else}}:
          ${{pair.key}}: ${{pair.value}}

The template.yml:
parameters:
- name: person_update
  type: object
  default: {}

steps:
- script: |
    echo "${PERSON}"
  env:
    PERSON: ${{ convertToJson(parameters.person_update) }}

Result:


This should achieve the same result
- template: templates/template.yml 
  parameters:
      person:
        first_name: ${{ parameters.person.first_name }}
        last_name: ${{ parameters.person.last_name} }
        role: "Teacher"


Thanks for the comment, but I want to make role dynamic. I'm looking for a way to send partial object and use default value for the keys that is not specified in the partial object.

Once main.yml gets a value for person passed in, that is the value of the object, the default is only used when nothing is passed in. The only way we can get individual defaults in main.yml is to make each attribute as a parameter. Since parameters are processed at compile time, there is not much that can be done with those except for passing around as is and then process at the final receiving end. Theoretically a variable can be created and its name passed to templates (name not the value) but that is more like a work around and flaky. I guess dealing with this template.yml isn't optimal?

I can create individual defaults in main.yml and make each attribute as a parameter, but it is too verbose. That's why I was looking into if partially overriding default values in object type parameter was supported by Azure

TL;DR you cannot partially override properties of an object parameter in Azure YAML pipelines.
But you can use coalesce function to provide default values for properties that are not set.
Example
templates/template.yml
parameters:
   - name: person
     type: object

steps:
  - script: |
      echo "First name: ${{ coalesce(parameters.person.first_name, 'Jane') }}"
    displayName: 'Display first name'
  
  - script: |
      echo "Last name: ${{ coalesce(parameters.person.last_name, 'Doe') }}"
    displayName: 'Display last name'
  
  - script: |
      echo "Role: ${{ coalesce(parameters.person.role, 'Student') }}"
    displayName: 'Display role'

my-pipeline.yml
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

parameters:
   - name: person
     type: object
     default:
        first_name: "Jane"
        last_name: "Doe"
        role: "Student"

steps:
  - checkout: none

  - template: templates/template.yml 
    parameters:
      person: ${{ parameters.person }}

  - template: templates/template.yml 
    parameters:
      person:
        role: "Teacher"
  
  - template: templates/template.yml
    parameters:
      person:
        first_name: "John"
        last_name: "Smith"

